# HTML form separate columns with borders

Tags: css, html, forms, class

I have 4 columns and I need separate each column with borders. It looks like now:

[image: resume now]

How It should be (red/blue colors just for example):

[image: resume with columns]

Problem Is that I don't have any div for columns, I generating rows inside `<li> </li>` so 4 inputs inside `<li> </li>` is 1 row:

```
<form class="form-style-9">

<h2>Personal details</h2>
<ul>
<div id="personal-details">
<li>    

    <div class="test">
    <label for="Rank">Rank</label>
    <input id="Rank" type="text" name="Rank" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Rank" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="RankApplied">Rank Applied</label>
    <input id="RankApplied" type="text" name="RankApplied" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Rank Applied" />   
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="Vesselstype">Vessel's type</label>
    <input id="Vesselstype" type="text" name="Vesselstype" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Vessel's type" />  
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="datepicker2">Date Applied</label>
    <input id="datepicker2" type="date" name="datepicker2" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="Date Applied" />
    </div>
</li>

<li>    
    <div class="test">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="First Name" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
    <input id="nationality" type="text" name="nationality" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Nationality" />    
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="height">Height</label>
    <input id="height" type="text" name="height" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Height" />   
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="na">Nearest airport</label>
    <input id="na" type="text" name="na" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="Nearest airport" />
    </div>
</li>

<li>    
    <div class="test">
    <label for="sname">Surename</label>
    <input id="sname" type="text" name="sname" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Surename" />   
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="noc">No. of children</label>
    <input id="noc" type="number" name="noc" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="No. of children" />  
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="weight">Weight</label>
    <input id="weight" type="number" name="weight" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Weight" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="test4">
    <label for="languages">Languages</label>
    <input id="languages" type="text" name="languages" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="Languages" />
    </div>
</li>

<li>    
    <div class="test">
    <label for="datepicker">Date of Birth</label>
    <input id="datepicker" type="date" name="datepicker" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Date of Birth"  />   
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="nok">Next of kin</label>
    <input id="nok" type="text" name="nok" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Next of kin" />    
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="coe">Color of eyes</label>
    <input id="coe" type="text" name="coe" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Color of eyes" />  
    </div>

    <div class="test4">
    <label for="english">English</label>
    <input id="english" type="text" name="english" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="English" />
    </div>
</li>

<li>    
    <div class="test">
    <label for="pob">Place of Birth</label>
    <input id="pob" type="text" name="pob" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="Place of Birth" />
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="nonok">Name of Next of Kin</label>
    <input id="nonok" type="text" name="nonok" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Name of Next of Kin" />    
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="coh">Color of hair</label>
    <input id="coh" type="text" name="coh" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Color of hair" />  
    </div>

    <div class="test4">
    <label for="german">German</label>
    <input id="german" type="text" name="german" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="German" />
    </div>
</li>

<li>    
    <div class="test">
    <label for="HomeAddress">Home Address</label>
    <input id="HomeAddress" type="text" name="HomeAddress" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Home Address" />   
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="aonok">Address of Next of Kin</label>
    <input id="aonok" type="text" name="aonok" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Address of Next of Kin" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="os">Overall size</label>
    <input id="os" type="text" name="os" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Overall size" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="test4">
    <label for="spain">Spain</label>
    <input id="spain" type="text" name="spain" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="Spain" />
    </div>
</li>

<li>    
    <div class="test">
    <label for="TelNo">Telephone No.</label>
    <input id="TelNo" type="text" name="TelNo" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Telephone No." />  
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="TelNo">Telephone No.</label>
    <input id="TelNo" type="text" name="TelNo" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Telephone No." />  
    </div>

    <div class="test">
    <label for="sz">Shoe size</label>
    <input id="sz" type="text" name="sz" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Shoe size" />    
    </div>

    <div class="test4">
    <label for="BankDetails">Bank Details</label>
    <input id="BankDetails" type="text" name="BankDetails" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="Bank Details" />
    </div>
</li>

</div>
```

Have you any ideas how can I achieve that? Here is [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6x3pmek5/)

Comment: why didn't you use table?... it is much easier.

Comment: @SamTengWong I don't have many practice with that, so I'm doing It in the way what I can. I really don't know how to achieve results like this with table...

Comment: you can do it using nested tables.... a table within a table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you strongly need to keep it as row-wise, you have the option of using `absolute`ly positioned, divs.

```css
#personal-details{
  position: relative;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li{
  width: 25%;
}
.parent{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.borders{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 40px;
}
.border{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="personal-details">
  <ul>
    <li>this is first</li>
    <li>this is second</li>
    <li>this is third</li>
    <li>this is forth</li>
    <li>this is first</li>
    <li>this is second</li>
    <li>this is third</li>
    <li>this is forth</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="borders">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Note1

Please note that you should not put `div`s directly inside `ul` so this is incorrect:

```
<ul>
    <div>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

## Note2

That would be a better practice if you produce them, column-wise, so that way you don't need to monkey with your CSS.

## Desired markup

```
<ul id="personal-details">
    <li>
        <ul class="column">
            <li>Rank</li>
            <li>First name</li>
            <li>Surname</li>
            <li>Date of Birth</li>
            <li>Place of Birth</li>
            <li> ... </li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">
            <li>Rank</li>
            <li>Nationality</li>
            <li>No. of children</li>
            <li>Next of kin</li>
            <li>Name of Next of kin</li>
            <li> ... </li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

## Solution

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
#personal-details{
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#personal-details > li{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.column{
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul id="personal-details">
    <li>
        <ul class="column">
            <li>
                <label for="Rank">Rank</label>
                <input type="text" name="Rank" placeholder="Rank" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Firstname">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Firstname" placeholder="Firstname" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Rank">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="text" name="DateofBirth" placeholder="DateofBirth" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="PlaceofBirth">Place of Birth</label>
                <input type="text" name="PlaceofBirth" placeholder="Place of Birth" />
            </li>
            <li> ... </li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">
            <li>
                <label for="RankApplied">Rank Applied</label>
                <input type="text" name="RankApplied" placeholder="RankApplied" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Nationality">Nationality</label>
                <input type="text" name="Nationality" placeholder="Nationality" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="NoOfChildren">No. Of Children</label>
                <input type="text" name="NoOfChildren" placeholder="NoOfChildren" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="NextOfKin">Next Of Kin</label>
                <input type="text" name="NextOfKin" placeholder="NextOfKin" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="NameOfNextOfKin">Name of Next of kin</label>
                <input type="text" name="NameOfNextOfKin" placeholder="NameOfNextOfKin" />
            </li>
            <li> ... </li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">
            <li>
                <label for="Rank">Rank</label>
                <input type="text" name="Rank" placeholder="Rank" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Firstname">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Firstname" placeholder="Firstname" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Rank">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="text" name="DateofBirth" placeholder="DateofBirth" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="PlaceofBirth">Place of Birth</label>
                <input type="text" name="PlaceofBirth" placeholder="Place of Birth" />
            </li>
            <li> ... </li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">
            <li>
                <label for="RankApplied">Rank Applied</label>
                <input type="text" name="RankApplied" placeholder="RankApplied" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Nationality">Nationality</label>
                <input type="text" name="Nationality" placeholder="Nationality" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="NoOfChildren">No. Of Children</label>
                <input type="text" name="NoOfChildren" placeholder="NoOfChildren" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="NextOfKin">Next Of Kin</label>
                <input type="text" name="NextOfKin" placeholder="NextOfKin" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="NameOfNextOfKin">Name of Next of kin</label>
                <input type="text" name="NameOfNextOfKin" placeholder="NameOfNextOfKin" />
            </li>
            <li> ... </li>
            <li> ... </li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, I really don't care if It will be row-wise or column-wise, but I failed to make column-wise, so made It in this way.

Comment: Looks like I done something wrong. You provided each `<li></li>` as column, but I have 4 columns inside 1 `<li></li>`. Like `<li> first second third fourth</li>`. Seems to be hard make it with my sample data...

Comment: Is it possible to give 1st and 3rd column red and 2nd and 4th column blue. I think OP want's op like that.

Comment: @ketan that needs minor style change, though she/he has huge problem in producing markup yet

Comment: @Trix thank you for you help, I'll check It a bit later and tell you If It worked for me. So do you think is better to make It column-wise rather than row-wise?

Comment: @Trix so in Desired markup part should I use those divs where you provided before? If yes, so where? after each `<ul class="column">`?

Comment: @Infinity Please check updated answer, last part `Solution`. The problem is that you dont read the answer. you just want to gain your output and do not invest enough time

Comment: Thanks for an edit. I've read your answer just missed something. In this case I have different format from that I had before, title of text field is in left side instead of top. And If title is in left side of field, fields should be aligned, could you help with that?

Comment: @Trix thank you for your help, but I've asked for borders only, now you suggested way to recreate form and after using your method titles appears in left side of text box instead of top. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If to keep your existing markup, here is an option (though you might need to adjust the values a little)

To be noted, having a `<div id="personal-details">` as a direct child of `ul` is invalid markup and should be removed. You can put the id on the `ul` instead.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/6x3pmek5/8/)

```
ul {
  position: relative;
}
ul li:first-child .test:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 23.5%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul li:first-child .test:nth-child(2):before {
  left: calc(23.5% + 1px);
  width: 24%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul li:first-child .test:nth-child(3):before {
  left: calc(47.5% + 1px);
  width: 24%;
}
ul li:first-child .test:nth-child(4):before {
  left: calc(71.5% + 1px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change that in following way.

```
<form class="form-style-9 clearfix">

<h2>Personal details</h2>
<ul>
<div id="personal-details">

<div class="col clearfix">
    <div class="test">
    <label for="Rank">Rank</label>
    <input id="Rank" type="text" name="Rank" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Rank" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="First Name" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="sname">Surename</label>
    <input id="sname" type="text" name="sname" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Surename" />   
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="pob">Place of Birth</label>
    <input id="pob" type="text" name="pob" class="field-style field-split25-4 align-left" placeholder="Place of Birth" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col clearfix">
    <div class="test">
    <label for="RankApplied">Rank Applied</label>
    <input id="RankApplied" type="text" name="RankApplied" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Rank Applied" />   
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
    <input id="nationality" type="text" name="nationality" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Nationality" />    
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="noc">No. of children</label>
    <input id="noc" type="number" name="noc" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="No. of children" />  
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col clearfix">
<div class="test">
    <label for="RankApplied">Rank Applied</label>
    <input id="RankApplied" type="text" name="RankApplied" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Rank Applied" />   
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
    <input id="nationality" type="text" name="nationality" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Nationality" />    
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="noc">No. of children</label>
    <input id="noc" type="number" name="noc" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="No. of children" />  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col clearfix">
<div class="test">
    <label for="RankApplied">Rank Applied</label>
    <input id="RankApplied" type="text" name="RankApplied" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Rank Applied" />   
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
    <input id="nationality" type="text" name="nationality" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Nationality" />    
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <label for="noc">No. of children</label>
    <input id="noc" type="number" name="noc" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="No. of children" />  
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

> Blockquote

```
.form-style-9{

    background: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 6px solid #305A72;
}
.form-style-9 ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.form-style-9 ul li{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1.25%;
    min-height: 58px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li  .field-style{
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.form-style-9 ul li  .field-style:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #B0CFE0;
    border:1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-split{
    width: 49%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-split25{
   /* float: left;
    width: 24%;
    margin-right: 1.25%;*/
    height: 40px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-split25-4{
    /*float: left;
    width: 24%;
    margin-right: 0;*/
    height: 40px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li .field-full{
    width: 100%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input.align-left{
    /*float:left;*/
}
.form-style-9 ul li input.align-right{
    float:right;
}
.form-style-9 ul li textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="button"], 
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="submit"] {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3985B1;
    background-color: #216288;
    border: 1px solid #17445E;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="button"]:hover, 
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2D77A2 5%, #337DA8 100%);
    background-color: #28739E;
}


.formcol{
float: left;
padding: 2px;
} 
.formcol label {

font-weight: bold;
display:block;
} 
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.test {
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.image-div {
    margin-right: 4%;
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;      
}
.image-upload {
  float:right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.image-preview {
  float:right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.test4 {
  float:left;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.test-label {  
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.test-label1 {  
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.removeRow{
height:auto;
width:auto;
max-width:12px;
max-height:12px;
}
.div-format-30 {
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1.25%;
  border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.div-format-30 td{
    margin-top:20px;
  float:left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1.25%;
  border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.split33 {
  float:left;
  width: 28%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.split33right {
  float:right;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.div-format {
  font-size:12px;
  float:left;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  border: 1px solid #B0CFE0;
}
.test4 {
  float:left;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
}
.header {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-bottom: .25%;
}
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
.form-style-9 ul li input[type="submit"] {
  width: 10%;
}
.resume-title {
    color: #af5d86;
}
.container {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.personal-details {
    padding-bottom:1.25%;
}
.col{
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
    margin-bottom: 1.25%;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must to do this :

1) make li vertical and change content in your example to specific it vertically .

2) but id to all li and in css make the border like this

```
<li id='first-column'> any thing</li>
<li id='second-column'> any thing</li>
```

css=>

```
#first-column { border:1px red solid; }

#second-column { border:1px blue solid; }
```

Comment: if you look at his code ,he used 4 li in horizontal  he can use one id to each li and then make border .

<li id='1'><li>
<li id='2'><li>
<li id='3'><li>
<li id='4'><li>